# jQuery, table, CSS and changing tr width: what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, resize

I'm opening exceptionally my website (with my 3rd high performance framework), in hoping that someone will help me to solve the problem.

Here's the page that works flawlessly, go there:

http://www.papdevis.fr/recherche/

You will see this:

[image: good url]

Click on this (fake) button:

`"De l'aide ? Cliquez ici"`

When you click on the button, its size doesn't change (that's what I want), like this:

[image: good url 2]

See? It's opening great, that's nice!

Now same JavaScript, same ids, but in a table:

http://www.papdevis.fr/devis-creer-editer/

You will see this:

[image: problem before click]

Click on the same (fake) button:

`"De l'aide ? Cliquez ici"`

And errrrrrrg!!! the width changes! See how:

[image: problem after click]

See? How comes it doesn't work? I absolutely don't know where the problem comes from.
I've been trying to change td sizes and everything I could find (including dozens of jquery/table/resize stackoverflow questions) but I didn't manage to "show" the "help" `<tr>` properly: it's never resized to the right width.

This code in the js file `metier.js` is problematic:

```
slides.hide();
$('#slideInner').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $(divEnglobe).show('slow', function() {
    slideWidth = $(divTailleReference).innerWidth();
    slides.css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    }); 
    slides.show();
```

How comes?

Comment: Worked fine for me in both places. FF 8.0 on Win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`td` and `tr` elements are *inline* elements and cannot have a *width*.

If you would make the elements [`display: inline-block`](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/), it would work!
It is supported in [all major browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Edit: I quickly posted a possible answer, but I now see that your code already works like you intended in my browser (Chrome, Windows 7). The problem might be something else!

Comment: td can have a width using css/style, but tr for sure has no width.

Comment: again thought you can inline the tr. Only some browsers won't like this.
Worth mentioning that inline-block doesn't work in IE7. But who cares about IE now they are auto updating:)

Comment: i've tested it: ubuntu 10.04, firefox, chrome and safari have the same (annoying) behavior....